# Record triggered flow. Work around for adding a pause/wait?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow

So I'm trying to create a record triggered flow from the Quote object.

My current process waits until a Quote hits a certain stage, then checks if a field value exists. If it doesn't exist, it updates the related Account record. If it does exists, run the update process on the Quote record.

What I'm wanting to do is have a wait/pause (or a process that waits until a field value is updated) but it appears I cannot do that with a record triggered flow.

Here is my flow. I've highlighted where I'd like the process to wait until there is confirmation that the record was created/imported. What's the best practice for this?

[image: Customer / Quote Creation Flow]

Answer (score 2):

[Pause elements](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_pause.htm&type=5) can only be on autolaunched flows.

> Flows that contain Pause elements must be autolaunched. If a flow includes Pause elements and screens, choice, or choice sets, you can’t activate or run it.

Likewise, if you create an autolaunched flow with a pause element and reference it in your record-triggered flow you'll get the following error

> A flow referenced by a Subflow element in a record-triggered flow can't include Pause elements.

There isn't a workaround currently. You have other tools at your disposal to replace *most* use-cases.

- [Scheduled paths](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows/add-a-scheduled-task-to-your-flow)
- The ability to create *other* record-triggered flows to capture *other* criteria being met

You didn't share many specifics, but considering the screenshot and it being a DML, I'm not sure a "pause" is what you need anyway. It looks like you're waiting for a "*condition*" to be met on some other object. In that case, you can have a trigger on the record you're thinking of "waiting" for to check that `import` has changed and is true. That would involve creating another record-triggered flow on that object and updating the records there instead.

Comment: This is not correct
"As such, you could create an autolaunched flow to handle your pause logic that you call from the Record-Triggered Flow which would allow you to wait to meet your requirement" ERROR A flow referenced by a Subflow element in a record-triggered flow can't include Pause elements.

Comment: Thanks @DanSkill - updated answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to update a record when a field changes.
The best practice is to create a record-triggered flow for the object where the update is expected and orchestrate the update from there.
There is no need for 'wait' element of the flow.

---

Re: Kris Goncalves

> There isn't a workaround currently. You have other tools at your disposal to replace most use-cases.

You CAN invoke an auto-launched flow from a process builder with a condition record created.